# Microsoft Teams azure botframework ICON

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm looking way to change icons of my bot (botframework botbuilder c# azure web app) using manifest.json (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema) they work like a charme for green icon and doesn't work for the 2 red circle ? :' : 
[image]

I didn't know if it's a problem due to the picture but i have following the site
 and preconization : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

Note : All icon work if i'm deploy the bot using channel link registration on Azure portal.

Sincerely,
Pascal.

Comment: Could you link the icon images as well?

Comment: Hello Mark, sorry for the time to respond. I have use multiple icon but this errors append when i try to change the icon to another.

Comment: If possible, posting the icon image itself would aid in helping you to figure out what is wrong with changing the images.

Comment: I have find the solution it"s not a problem off the icon image on manifest. But it's a problem due to the icon setting in Azure Portal. Thx for your help.

Comment: Please post your solution below in case other users run into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Unable-to-change-bot-profile-icon/m-p/713235) this is a caching issue. Related to the fact, that all personal chats continue in the previous thread, and threads can't be deleted.

The claim is that new users will see the correct icon (I have not verified this).

---

UPDATE:

The 'red' icons are set in the Teams App [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-package#icons) json package.

The 'green' icon set in the Azure App Registration, being registered with the bot app.